# Running a Bash Command in a loop in a Python Script

Tags: python, linux, bash, parsing, loops

I have this script of mine and it is for modifying some data I gather from GPS module. I run this code but it says there is a syntax error and I couldn't understand why there is an error, normally I use that bash command for parsing, can't it be used in a Python loop?

**

```
import serial
import struct
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 4800, timeout = 1)
file = open("/home/pi/GPSWIFI.csv", "w")
file.write('\n')
for i in range(0,5):
       val = ser.readline();
       print >> file ,i,',',val
       cat /home/pi/GPSWIFI.csv | grep GPGGA | cut -c19-42 >GPSWIFIMODIFIED.csv
file.close()
```

**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says it is a syntax error ;                                     File "GPSWIFII.py", line 10
cat /home/pi/GPSWIFI.csv | grep GPGGA | cut -c19-42 >GPSWIFIMODIFIED.csv

Comment: You can't just run bash commands directly like that. You need to [import subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and set the parameter `shell=True`. You might find [this tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators) helpful.

Comment: why are you writing a newline at the start?

Comment: Because I will change the format from write to append and all the data will be separated by one line in the same file.

Comment: and do you know about how I can make the date which I acquire from ntp can be printed in front of "i" in by adding a word in print >> file ,i,',',val ?

Comment: you can create a file with `a` also. You don't have to open with `w`.How are you getting the date?

Comment: Thanks for that, network time protocol updates the date itself through gps, my headless computer always has real time, but I don't know how to print that real time, when I type date on the terminal I see the date and time and what I want is it to be in front of each lines, because each line would have different data in a different time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you believe you could mix bash and python together as if they were one language?  I'm not trying to be accusing, but I'd like to understand where new user's assumptions come from.

Comment: Actually I am studying electronics and I am new in programming, very new, I thought I could make the script run a command.

Comment: No, that's not what I am asking. This is a Python script, but the command is Bash... Did you see somewhere that the two were interchangeable?

Comment: No I didn't see it anywhere, I just tried to call the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running bash commands in python can be done using `os.system` function, or, more recommended, through `subprocess.Popen`. You can find more info here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

It would be better if you used python-specific implementation instead, like this:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 4800, timeout = 1)
file = open("/home/pi/GPSWIFIMODIFIED.csv", "w")
file.write('\n')
for i in range(0,5):
       val = ser.readline();
       if val.find("GPGGA")==-1: continue
       print >> file ,i,',',val[18:42]
file.close()
```

note that slice in python (this `val[18:42]`) is indexed from 0